# Full text search order by closest match

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT user_id, user_name.fullname, live, likes,
MATCH (fullname, email, live) AGAINST (:search_I IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM profile LEFT JOIN user_name ON user_id=user_id
WHERE MATCH (fullname, email, live) AGAINST (:search_II IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevance DESC 

bindValue(':search_I', $search...);
bindValue(':search_II', $search...);//PDO can't use same one twice
```

I have a query use **FULL TEXT search**, I need to **order by the closest match on top**.

However this query is not working, It didn't order anything.

I did a testing, search 123@hotmail.com

2 rows in my db, abc@hotmail.com & 123@hotmail.com

It return 2 rows but didn't put the closest match on top(123@hotmail.com)

anyone know where is the problems?

Comment: What are the values of of `:search_I` and `:search_II`?  Perhaps you have these backwards.

Comment: 2 are the same :search_I = $search, ;search_II=$search, PDO cant use  same bindValue twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default MySQL full text search has a minimum word length of 3 (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)).

So, your example of `'123@hotmail.com'` is only matching on `'hotmail'` and the two are equivalent.

You can change the default (*and* rebuild the index).  But, I'd suggest that you do testing with `'abcd@hotmail.com'` instead.

EDIT:

The definition of a word is buried a bit in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> The MySQL FULLTEXT implementation regards any sequence of true word
>   characters (letters, digits, and underscores) as a word. That sequence
>   may also contain apostrophes (“'”), but not more than one in a row.
>   This means that aaa'bbb is regarded as one word, but aaa''bbb is
>   regarded as two words. Apostrophes at the beginning or the end of a
>   word are stripped by the FULLTEXT parser; 'aaa'bbb' would be parsed as
>   aaa'bbb.

Because of the `where` clause, you can see that there is a match to both email addresses.  That match would have to be on `'hotmail'`.  The `'com'` and email name get chopped off because of the default minimum word length.

Comment: ha, i get it, so it didn't count full string include @?

Comment: so how can I change the default to miniimum length 2?